# Telerik load two radgrids on key pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a button which loads two radgrids. The first is "countries" (getting data from db fastly). The second is "cities" (getting data from db slowly). In aspx.cs it looks like:

```
grdCities.DataSource = doWork1();
grdCities.DataBind();

grdCountries.DataSource = doWork2();
grdCountries.DataBind();
```

Is there a way to render them to page independently from each other when data for corresponding grid is ready?
Should i use threads on server side and ajax to send it to page and how it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create new web page and try with the below code snippet.

**.ASPX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

            });
            function testclick() {

                var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>");
                ajaxManager.ajaxRequest("RadGrid1");
                ajaxManager.ajaxRequest("RadGrid2");

                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest" RequestQueueSize="10">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"></telerik:RadGrid>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server"></telerik:RadGrid>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return testclick();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.ASPX.CS**

```
public partial class Forum : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Init(object source, System.EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void NewMethod()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Custom1", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "name1", "custom1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "name2", "custom2");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "name3", "Radgrid1_" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
    }

    private void NewMethod2()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Custom1", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "name1", "custom1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "name2", "custom2");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "name3", "Radgrid2_" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        RadGrid2.DataSource = dt;
        RadGrid2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == "RadGrid1")
        {
            NewMethod();
        }
        else if (e.Argument == "RadGrid2")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            NewMethod2();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Thanks,
Jayesh Goyani